# how xsd can represent different xml file?

Tags: xml, xsd

if I have this XML data 
Main.xml

```
  <SigmodRecord>
 <issue>
  <volume>11</volume> 
  <number>1</number> 
 <articles>
 <article>
  <title>Annotated Bibliography on Data Design.</title> 
  <initPage>45</initPage> 
  <endPage>77</endPage> 
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Anthony I. Wasserman</author> 
  <author position="01">Karen Botnich</author> 
  </authors>
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Architecture of Future Data Base Systems.</title> 
  <initPage>30</initPage> 
  <endPage>44</endPage> 
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Lawrence A. Rowe</author> 
  <author position="01">Michael Stonebraker</author> 
  </authors>
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Database Directions III Workshop Review.</title> 
  <initPage>8</initPage> 
  <endPage>8</endPage> 
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Tom Cook</author> 
  </authors>
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Errors in 'Process Synchronization in Database Systems'.</title> 
  <initPage>9</initPage> 
  <endPage>29</endPage> 
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Philip A. Bernstein</author> 
  <author position="01">Marco A. Casanova</author> 
  <author position="02">Nathan Goodman</author> 
  </authors>
  </article>
  </articles>
  </issue>
</SigmodRecord>
```

and this schema Main.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="SigmodRecord">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="issue">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="volume" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="articles">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="article">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
                          <xsd:element name="initPage" type="xsd:int" />
                          <xsd:element name="endPage" type="xsd:int" />
                          <xsd:element name="authors">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                              <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="author">
                                  <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="position" type="xsd:int" />
                                  </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                              </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

it becomes 2 fragments like this 
Frag1.xml:

```
 <SigmodRecord>
 <issue>
  <volume>11</volume> 
  <number>1</number> 
 <articles>
 <article>
  <title>Annotated Bibliography on Data Design.</title> 
  <initPage>45</initPage> 
  <endPage>77</endPage> 
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Architecture of Future Data Base Systems.</title> 
  <initPage>30</initPage> 
  <endPage>44</endPage> 
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Database Directions III Workshop Review.</title> 
  <initPage>8</initPage> 
  <endPage>8</endPage> 
  </article>
 <article>
  <title>Errors in 'Process Synchronization in Database Systems'.</title> 
  <initPage>9</initPage> 
  <endPage>29</endPage> 
  </article>
  </articles>
  </issue>
</SigmodRecord>
```

Frag2.xml:

```
 <SigmodRecord>
<authors>
  <author position="00">Anthony I. Wasserman</author> 
  <author position="01">Karen Botnich</author> 
  </authors>
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Lawrence A. Rowe</author> 
  <author position="01">Michael Stonebraker</author> 
  </authors>
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Tom Cook</author> 
  </authors>
 <authors>
  <author position="00">Philip A. Bernstein</author> 
  <author position="01">Marco A. Casanova</author> 
  <author position="02">Nathan Goodman</author> 
  </authors>
</SigmodRecord>
```

how can I use one schema that can represent both of Fragments with keeping the original structure of the first XML.
In other words, is there any way to make Main.xsd represent Frag1.xsd+frag2.xsd
I do not want 2 schema only one!!?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The schema you are looking for looks something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="SigmodRecord">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="issue">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="volume" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="articles">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="article">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
                          <xsd:element name="initPage" type="xsd:int" />
                          <xsd:element name="endPage" type="xsd:int" />
                          <xsd:element ref="authors"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element ref="authors"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="authors">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="author">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="position" type="xsd:int" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This schema will work for all the 3 xml fragments.

Comment: regards.. I will check and if I have further question. may ask you?

Comment: @Dena, not a problem. Let me know if the schema fits your requirement.

Comment: can I use SigmodRecord or issue as a root for authors Fragments . But I have a question How about if I use article (not articles) as a root for author Fragment to keep the parent child relationship also please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929848/joining-xml-fragments

Comment: @Dena, the structure of the schema is according to your requirement. The relationship between the elements determines the position of the elements in the schema. For example, your existing schema can be interpreted as 'one issue has several articles' and 'each article has several authors'. I suggest that you define this kind of relationship on a paper first and then design the schema.

Comment: article/authors needs to be optional to satisfy frag1.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like @*Devendra D. Chavan* already provided a solution for you. I just want to provide general rule **Any global element defined in xsd can be a potential root element in the instance document**

Comment: you meant I can use SigmodRecord or issue as a root for authors Fragments . But I have a question How about if I use article (not articles) as a root for author Fragment to keep the parent child relationship .. Thanks @Pangea

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you should make the content model for SigmodRecord be an xs:choice with the two alternatives being Authors or Issue.

You'll get much more reusability of the definitions in the schema if you use more global top-level element (and perhaps type) declarations. A deeply nested schema like this, with only one top-level element declaration, can only describe one input document format - there's no provision for elements such as Author or Affiliation appearing in different places in different messages.

Some people like to make use of the xsi:type attribute for this kind of scenario: two alternative types for the SigmodRecord element, selected in the instance by using `<SigmodRecord xsi:type="authors">` or `<SigmodRecord xsi:type="issue">`.