# joining xml fragments

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to join these 2 fragments together by id or whatever .. I have 2 ways

```
<SigmodRecord>
 <issue>
  <volume>11</volume> 
  <number>1</number> 
 <articles>
 <article> <id>1</id> ....  </article>
 <article> <id>2</id>....  </article>
 <article> <id>3</id>....  </article>
 <article> <id>4</id> .....  </article>
</articles>
</issue>
</SigmodRecord>
```

---

```
<SigmodRecord>
 <authors><id>1</id>...</authors> 
 <authors><id>2</id> ...</authors>
 <authors><id>3</id>...  </authors>
 <authors><id>4</id>....</authors>
</SigmodRecord>
```

---

the problem with the first one that this will increase the file size by adding elements if I already have huge data
or another way is attribute like  and 
but I need something more lite and efficient how the schema will look like referring to this question [how xsd can represent different xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928618/how-xsd-can-represent-different-xml-file) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join by id, then you can have a attribute in the article node [authorIdRef]. This attribute can be used to link to a author node [uniqueId] containing the actual data. 
For example,

```
<article authorIdRef="author1"> ...  </article>
...
...
<authors>
    <author uniqueId="author1"> .... </author>
</authors
```

Note that in the above case the validation of the data (whether the linked author is present or not is to done entirely by the consumer of the xml. For example, it is possible to have an `authorIdRef="author1"` but in the authors node there is no author having its `uniqueId` as `author1`. 
The schema needs to be modified accordingly to reflect the additional attributes.